# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Snake (wrong name: snake2/Snake)

Tags: java

So I'm trying to build a 2D game of snake, and I'm almost done. My only issue is that when I try to run the program, I get tis error:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Snake
>   (wrong name: snake2/Snake)"

Usually it's just because I'm the the wrong directory or because I typed in the command wrong, but those reasons don't really seem to be the issue. The class with the main method is here: (the logic and 99% of the code is in a second class, also in package snake2)

```
package snake2;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Snake extends JFrame {

public Snake() {

    add(new Board());

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(320, 340);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setTitle("Snake");

    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Snake();
}
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to compile and run this program?

Answer (score 2):

This is perhaps because you are running it inside the package folder.

Try running it from the folder which contains the `snake2` folder (and don't go inside the `snake2` folder) and execute the java command as follows:

```
java snake2.Snake
```

Comment: I think real reason is not trying to run from inside package but rather using command java snake2/Snake - but still your command is the correct one